# Reusing previous inputs (old or new) for query-replace

Tags: query-replace, default

Most functions in emacs keep a default option, with the last arguments used. Is it possible to reuse some of the default arguments while changing others?

For example, when using search and replace, a string such as `Query replace (default thing1 -> thing2)` lets you reuse the last command, instead of typing it all over.  Is there a way to keep "thing1" as the first argument, but enter a new string in place of "thing2"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say you already did a `query-replace` of `thing1` with `thing2`.

Here is how it goes if you want to use `thing1` as the first argument again. It is not automatic but you don't have to type in the whole `thing1` either. The benefit of this approach is more more when doing `query-replace-regexp` and you need to repeat a very complex regexp.

- Call `query-replace` or `query-replace-regexp` again.
- Entering search expression: `M-p` `M-p` (yes, twice) - The first `M-p` will bring up `thing2` and the second will bring up `thing1`.
- Entering replace expression: Proceed with your use case where you want to enter a new string instead of `thing2`. Or if you change your mind and want to continue with `thing2`, do `M-p` `M-p` again!

Comment: Plain arrow-up also works.

Comment: I'm was hoping for a more automatic solution, but this does work.

Comment: @Lindydancer Thanks for adding that. I wouldn't have known as I have got used to not using the arrow keys, thanks to [hardcore-mode](https://github.com/magnars/hardcore-mode.el).

Comment: @user2699 Emacs automatically populates the `thing1` and `thing2`. Hitting `M-p` in the minibuffer will become instinctive once you realize you can do `M-p` in almost all the cases where you want to recall the previous string and want to save typing. I use it in isearch, when renaming files, query-replace(-regexp), etc

Comment: It's worth noting that these instructions will change in Emacs 25. Namely, a single `M-p` will bring up both previous inputs simultaneously.

Comment: It's also possible to use different histories for to and from using `query-replace-{to,from}-history-variable`.

Comment: @Malabarba: I came here to find out how, in Emacs25, I can choose `thing1` only but change the replacement string.