# Repeat regexp from isearc-forward-regexp on a subsequent replace-regexp?

Tags: regular-expressions, commands

I use `C-M-s` to search for a regexp. Then I use `M-x replace-regexp` to replace the same regexp with some string. Can I save typing the regexp for the second time?

Generally, when typing an argument for a command, and then the same argument for a different command, can I save typing the argument for the second time?

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/8144/115

Comment: just curious, regexp search is it `C-s` (or) `C-M-s`?

Comment: Hi Tim, the previous title was a duplicate of the question linked by @kaushalmodi. However, since the body asked specifically about `C-M-s`, there's a better possible answer that doesn't show up in the linked question. As such, I've edited your title so as to not be a duplicate, but you're free to rollback the edit if you're not happy.

Comment: @MadhavanKumar By default, `C-M-s` is bound to `isearch-forward-regexp` (regexp search). The same can also be invoked by doing `C-u C-s`. `C-s` is `isearch-forward` (no regexp).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I use `C-M-s` to search for a regexp. Then I use `M-x replace-regexp`. Can I save typing the regexp for the second time?

Yes, instead of exiting the incremental search, just hit `M-%` (which,
by the way, is the global binding for `query-replace`). This will use
the search string you've just typed and only prompt you for a
replacement.

This will work both on `isearch-forward-regexp` (`C-M-s`) and on
regular `isearch` (`C-s`), and it will inherit the type of search you
were using (regexp and non-regexp respectively). You can also use
`C-M-%`, which does the same thing except it uses regexps regardless
of the type of isearch you were in.

Comment: Question: what if I have already exited the search? How can I bring out the query in M-x replace-regexp?

Comment: @Tim start the search again, hit `M-p`, then follow the above.

Comment: when I use M-x occur to do regex search, M-% doesn't switch to regrex replace. Any way?

Comment: @Tim not that I'm aware, but it's worth a feature request.