# How to combine the history of isearch and query-replace?

Tags: isearch, query-replace

I often use isearch (`C-s` normally or `/` in evil) and then want to use that query (or part of it) for replacing. [This answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/8146/8283) explains how to cycle history, but `M-p` cycles the history for each mode *separately* so I don't see isearch queries from query-replace.

Ideally, the query I used for either search is automatically saved and I can use a key binding to insert the query into a buffer or minibuffer.

Example: search for "fib-function", `C-h f` and insert "fib-function" for help, or helm-do-grep to search for it in files, or just insert it into the current file to start defining it.

Comment: If you use Helm, you could use `helm-minibuffer-history` that shows all inputs. and bind it to a key in `isearch-mode-map`.

Comment: Using this: `(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-u") 'helm-minibuffer-history)` causes my entire buffer to be replaced with whatever I select from the history (and I can only select the first item). Also, I can't use that to insert into helm: `helm: Error: Trying to run helm within a running helm session`.

Comment: Weird, working fine for me in Isearch. So, try `(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-l") 'helm-minibuffer-history)` if it works. Are you using Spacemacs? Also, if you see a Helm buffer that gives you a list of strings, it's working as expected. Select an item from the list and press `RET`. Then the input will be inserted into the minibuffer.

Comment: I am using spacemacs and using `/` to start isearch. I get the same result with that map: I get a helm buffer giving a list of strings separated by ----, but I can't type to narrow down the list and I can't use C-j to move down the list. Typing anything narrows the list to helm-minibuffer-history (the first item in the list). Then my buffer is replaced with helm-minibuffer-history.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Customize option `query-replace-from-history-variable` (or `query-replace-to-history-variable`, or both).  Point to `search-ring` or `regexp-search-ring` instead of `query-replace-history`.

Comment: Thanks! `(setq query-replace-from-history-variable 'regexp-search-ring)` worked to join the spacemacs `/` history with visual-regexp-steroids. For anyone following along at home, the `from` refers to the search history and `to` means the replacement history, so you can track them independently. `C-h v` explains what they mean.